# Elegant way to calculate multiple rows/columns of items in Thymeleaf when iterating over a foreach

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I currently have a list of objects that's being passed to thymeleaf template.  List for example.  For testing I was simply iterating over it and outputting with each element being an li :

```
 <ol>
 <li th:each="book : ${library.comedy}" th:text="${book.name}"></li>
 </ol>
```

the library object has multiple lists, in this case there's comedy, horror etc etc and I was outputting each of them.

I've now started to use a bootstrap template and have encountered a small issue in that the template uses rows and columns with them being nested several deep.  Currently it displays 3 in a row and then repeats.

(This is boilerplate text from the template)

```
<div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                        <div class="game-item">
                            <img th:src="@{/img/games/1.jpg}" alt="#">
                            <h5>Zombie Appocalipse 2</h5>
                            <a href="game-single.html" class="read-more">Read More  <img th:src="@{/img/icons/double-arrow.png}" alt="#"/></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                        <div class="game-item">
                            <img th:src="@{/img/games/2.jpg}" alt="#">
                            <h5>Dooms Day</h5>
                            <a href="game-single.html" class="read-more">Read More  <img th:src="@{/img/icons/double-arrow.png}" alt="#"/></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                        <div class="game-item">
                            <img th:src="@{/img/games/3.jpg}" alt="#">
                            <h5>The Huricane</h5>
                            <a href="game-single.html" class="read-more">Read More  <img th:src="@{/img/icons/double-arrow.png}" alt="#"/></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I need to create a game item per book that I have in my list, but I also need to create multiple rows as there will be more than 3.

Currently the only way I can think to do it is to get a count of the items in the list, take the mod and then use that in a for loop creating a new row each time we get to 3.  But that 'feels' messy and I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution?

thanks in advance for any help, suggestions or advice.  I may be looking at this completely wrong in which case I welcome any help you're willing to give.

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509689/combining-conditions-and-iterations-in-thymeleaf/39515137#39515137

Comment: @Metroids, perfect, thankyou!  I'd found a couple of other examples by widening the search but this one is also great.  Will upvote it, and thank you!