# how to get the result of database in thymleaf horizontally (4 records in a row)

Tags: java, html, css, thymeleaf

Please, someone, help me to get the result of the database(MySQL) in thymleaf horizontally (4 records in each row) and then next line again 4 rows. when I add a new product it will again add result in beside the last result in Thymleaf.

If any more information is required please let me know. I'm new in programming and wanted to learn.

Controller code

```
@GetMapping("/product")
public ModelAndView getProduct() {
    
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    
    List<Product> product= pRepo.findAll();
    
    model.addObject("products", product);
    model.setViewName("product");
    
    return model;
}
```

Thymleaf code

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family:cursive;

}

.price {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.card input {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.card input:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.card img:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1); /* Safari 3-8 */
  transform: scale(2.5); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Home</title>

  </head>
  <body style="background-color:#F0F3F4;">
    
    <div>
      <table>   
          <tr th:each="product: ${products}">

              <div class="card" style="align-items: center;">
               <img th:src="@{'/uploads/' + ${product.filename}}" alt="product name" width="150" height="150" />
                <h2 th:text="${product.prodName}"></h2>
                <p th:text="${product.prodDesc}" />
                <p th:text=" '₹ '+ ${product.price}" />
                <p><input type="button" value="Add to Cart" /></p>
              </div>

              <br />
           </tr> 
      </table>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to show a list of product which is in the database in proper view as I told in the above line.

See the sample output: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gv6G.png)
But I'm getting an only a single-column result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining conditions and iterations in thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509689/combining-conditions-and-iterations-in-thymeleaf)

Comment: the result which is coming in the column and I want the result to be fetched in row-wise.

Comment: Right - the question I linked to shows how to do that.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot picture in the question, so can you help me to get align the dynamic cards (4 cols - cards) in single row? Like list of products display in amazon.

Comment: That is what the approach in the linked answer does for you. So instead of processing a single `List<Product>`, you are processing a `List<List<Product>>` where each sublist contains 4 products (one row!) because of the partitioning function. You can embed that partitioning utility into Thymeleaf, or do the partitioning on the server. But look how the Thymeleaf has 2 levels of nested iteration in it -  that is how you control each row of 4 items. Give it a try. (Or use a CSS grid instead.)

Comment: @andrewjames can you please help me with the code? I'm really confused now and not getting what to do...please help me with code if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the following changes to your approach:

**1) Add the `commons-collections4` library to your project.**

For example, if you are using Maven, you can add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

This is just added as a convenience, to save us from writing some extra lines of code, when we split our list into partitioned sub-lists.

**2) In your controller, do the following:**

Add the following import:

```
import org.apache.commons.collections4.ListUtils;
```

You use this import to convert your list of products into a list of lists:

```
ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
List<Product> product= pRepo.findAll();

// Partition the list into the required sub-lists:
int partitionSize = 3;
List<List<Product>> displayRows = ListUtils.partition(products, partitionSize);

// use this new list of lists:
model.addObject("displayRows", displayRows);

model.setViewName("product");
return model;
```

Now, you have a list of sub-lists, where each sub-list contains 3 items (or maybe less than 3 in the final sub-list).

Each sub-list represents ***one row of data*** in your HTML table.

**3) Change your Thymeleaf template**

```
    <div>
        <table>   
            <tr th:each="displayRow : ${displayRows}">
                <td th:each="product: ${displayRow}">

                    <div class="card" style="align-items: center;">
                        <img th:src="@{'/uploads/' + ${product.filename}}" 
                             alt="product name" width="150" height="150" />
                        <h2 th:text="${product.prodName}"></h2>
                        <p th:text="${product.prodDesc}" />
                        <p th:text=" '&#8377; '+ ${product.price}" />
                        <p><input type="button" value="Add to Cart" /></p>
                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr> 
        </table>
    </div>
```

We are using 2 levels of iteration: The first is for each table row - which is each sub-list.  The second is for each item in the row (the table cells).

**One point to note**: In your Thymeleaf template you are using this:

```
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
```

I do not recommend this. I would always recommend using UTF-8:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

And, then you are also hard-coding the rupee symbol directly in your template: `₹`. But because this is embedded in HTML, you should use the HTML display sequence instead (like I do in the above code): `&#8377;`. But if you formatted your currency amount on the server you would not have to use this code - you would be able to use the currency symbol directly.

The final result is as follows (note I do not have any pictures in my test set-up):

[image]

You can add some more CSS to improve the spacing between cards.

Comment: thank you so much for your sincere effort to help me and some other people who need this in the future. Before your answer, I tried solving by CSS and I came up with the solution, which is I'm going to post as an answer as well to answer this question in another way. But I'm appreciating your answer the most.

Comment: I am glad you have a solution. I can see you used a [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) - that was another good approach, (as I mentioned briefly in a previous comment). Depending on the visual behavior you want, a grid can be more flexible in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried solving this issue by adding CSS to the front end code.

```
    .jobs {
  list-style: none;
}

.jobs li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  
}

.jobs::after {
  content: "";
  display: grid;
  clear: both;
}




<ul class="jobs">
        <div th:each="product: ${products}">
            
            <li>
                <div class="card" style="align-items: center;">
                 <img th:src="@{'/uploads/' + ${product.filename}}" alt="product name" width="150" height="150" />
                  <h2 th:text="${product.prodName}"></h2>
                  <p th:text="${product.prodDesc}" />
                  <p th:text=" '₹ '+ ${product.price}" />
                  <p><input type="button" value="Add to Cart" /></p> 
                </div>
            </li>
                <br>    
            
        </div>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are combining two approaches. You have table rows for the output but no cells so you can use `<th>` for the header and `<td>` for the data to distribute the data horizontally. The other approach is if you want to use css grid - [take a look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Auto-placement_in_CSS_Grid_Layout)

Maybe just try with product name until you get the format you want, then add the other elements.

Comment: I want the result like in CSS grid only the one link which you dropped, but for dyanamic value, because thymleaf unable to identify the ${product.prodName} values after applying css grid. can you please help me?