# How to iterate object list in thymeleaf

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I want to do the following scenario in thymeleaf:

There is a collection of Person-object(`List<Person> persons`) that is divided in four entry in each div like this:

```
<div>
    <span>name1</span>
    <span>name2</span>
    <span>name3</span>
    <span>name4</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>name5</span>
    <span>name6</span>
    <span>name7</span>
    <span>name8</span>
</div>
```

How is it possible by thymeleaf loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining conditions and iterations in thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509689/combining-conditions-and-iterations-in-thymeleaf) If you can't partition the list in the Thymeleaf template, like the answer does, then you can partition it in your Java code instead. But partitioning the list makes processing the list much easier.

Answer (score 0):

if without additional libraries you can use the following pattern:

```
   <!--
      /*
       * Create a sequence (array) of integer numbers going from x to y
       */
       ${#numbers.sequence(from,to,step)
    -->
    <th:block th:with="rowCount=${4}">
        <div th:each="offset : ${#numbers.sequence(0, persons.size() - 1, rowCount)}">
            <span th:each="rowNumber : ${#numbers.sequence(0, rowCount - 1)}"
                th:if="${offset + rowNumber &lt; persons.size()}"
                th:text="${persons.get(offset + rowNumber).name}">
            </span>
        </div>
    </th:block>
```