# thymeleaf : displaying n items in 3 columns

Tags: html, css, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

How can I display n - items from list into 3 columns using Thymeleaf ?

HTML Code :

```
<section>
    <div class="sectionTitle">
        <h1>Key Skills</h1>
    </div>
        <div class="sectionContent" th:each="skill : ${userProfile.getUserSkills()}">
            <li th:text="${skill.getSkillName()}">[Skill Name]</li>
        </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</section>
```

[image]

Comment: Something like this works as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509689/combining-conditions-and-iterations-in-thymeleaf/39515137#39515137

Answer (score 1):

found a solution (may not be perfect or optimal but it works!)

```
<section>
    <div class="sectionTitle">
        <h1>Key Skills</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="sectionContent">
        <span th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(0, 2)}">
            <ul class="skills">
                <div th:each="skill, index : ${userProfile.getUserSkills()}"
                    th:unless="${(index.index-i) % 3}">
                    <li th:text="${skill.getSkillName()}">[Skill Name]</li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </span>
    </div>
    
    <div class="clear"></div>
</section>
```

which produces [image]