# How to place objects from collection one after another?

Tags: java, html, outlook, thymeleaf, html-email

I making HTML for an Outlook email client.
I use thymeleaf to place collection of objects into table.
I have tried this, but **the problem is that objects arranged vertically**:

```html
<table width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr th:each="user:${users}">
        <td style="padding: 16px 24px 16px 24px;">
            <img src="cid:avatar"
                 alt="IMAGE">
        </td>
        <td style="padding: 16px 24px 16px 1px;">
            <span class="contact-name"
                  th:text="${user.fullName}">
                name
            </span>
            <span th:href="${link}"
                  class="contact-email"
                  th:text="${user.email}">
                email
            </span>
            <br/>
            <span class="contact-number"
                  th:text="${user.phoneNumber}">
                8900000000
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to make fixed number of cells wide and place them one after another. Like :
[image]
How can i do that ?
Remember that outlook doesn't allow many tags!

----UPD----
Ansver in comments!

Comment: Take a look at [Combining conditions and iterations in thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39515137/12567365), which uses Apache Commons Collections to partition the list. The example solution performs the partition in Thymeleaf. You can partition `users` in Java instead - and that may also make it easier to ensure the final partition is a full row, if that is needed.

Comment: Do you need this responsive too?